# Can SDL2 be programmed in C (as opposed to C++)?

Tags: c++, c, sdl, sdl-2

I'm very new to programming, and especially to using SDL2.

Most of the SDL2 tutorials that I have found are to create C++ programs. I was just wondering whether it's possible to create SDL2 in C programs, or whether it is simply only used for C++?

Comment: The tag wiki states that it is a C library, so I don't see why not.

Answer (score 6):

Yes; it is a C library with a C interface. There is nothing about it that requires C++.

Indeed, all those tutorials (if I had to wager) exhibit more C than C++ programming idioms.